# Парсинг XML с вложенными элементами

Tags: xml, golang

Есть файл xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <documents session_ui="4Aa246a6-D7e2-2465-a056-0234554369a3" version="1.26" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <move_order_notification action_id="601">
            <subject_id>95274000000041</subject_id>
            <receiver_id>95274000000003</receiver_id>
            <operation_date>2017-08-28T12:05:04+03:00</operation_date>
            <doc_num>2017/186543</doc_num>
            <doc_date>28.08.2017</doc_date>
            <turnover_type>1</turnover_type>
            <source>3</source>
            <contract_type>6</contract_type>
            <contract_num>18506005907 18 000044</contract_num>
            <order_details>
                <union>
                    <sscc_detail>
                        <sscc>147600887000000010</sscc>
                        <detail>
                            <gtin>11170012610151</gtin>
                            <series_number>100000001</series_number>
                            <cost>300</cost>
                            <vat_value>54</vat_value>
                        </detail>
                        <detail>
                            <gtin>11170012610153</gtin>
                            <series_number>100000333</series_number>
                            <cost>200</cost>
                            <vat_value>54</vat_value>
                        </detail>
                    </sscc_detail>
                    <cost>300</cost>
                </union>
                <union>
                    <sscc_detail>
                        <sscc>147600887000000015</sscc>
                    </sscc_detail>
                    <cost>300</cost>
                </union>
            </order_details>
        </move_order_notification>
    </documents>
```

Пытаюсь его распарсить [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tmrHw_Cfefp). Парсит до тега union и все. Предполагается, что OrderDetails601 будет содержать массив элементов union601 и т.д.,но нет. Почему так происходит? Что я упустил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно используете срезы. Метки должны быть на полях срезов, а не внутри них. То есть:

```golang
type OrderDetails601 struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name    `xml:"order_details"`
    Unions601 []*Union601 `xml:"union"`
}
```

И так далее. Рабочий код: https://play.golang.org/p/XLX72Itu2Fm.